# I'm new to flutter and dart language, i'm building pokedex and i want to have a different colors for my grid

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, colors

So, i want to have a different grid color which match with the type of each pokemon. What i have in mind so far is making something like a class where i can tell if the type is what then the color is what. But i do not know how to pull it off, so here's my code :

Here is the grid view code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Poke Dex"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
      ),
      body: pokeHub == null
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              children: pokeHub.pokemon
                  .map((poke) => Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => PokeDetail(
                                          pokemon: poke,
                                        )));
                          },
                          child: Hero(
                            tag: poke.img,
                            child: Card(
                              elevation: 5.0,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    height: 100.0,
                                    width: 100.0,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                            image: NetworkImage(poke.img))),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    poke.name,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            ),
```

i'm using json to call the data of the pokemon, here is the full json.

```
    class PokeHub {
  List<Pokemon> pokemon;

  PokeHub({this.pokemon});

  PokeHub.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['pokemon'] != null) {
      pokemon = new List<Pokemon>();
      json['pokemon'].forEach((v) {
        pokemon.add(new Pokemon.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.pokemon != null) {
      data['pokemon'] = this.pokemon.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Pokemon {
  int id;
  String num;
  String name;
  String img;
  List<String> type;
  String height;
  String weight;
  String candy;
  int candyCount;
  String egg;
  String spawnChance;
  String avgSpawns;
  String spawnTime;
  List<double> multipliers;
  List<String> weaknesses;
  List<NextEvolution> nextEvolution;
  List<PrevEvolution> prevEvolution;

  Pokemon(
      {this.id,
      this.num,
      this.name,
      this.img,
      this.type,
      this.height,
      this.weight,
      this.candy,
      this.candyCount,
      this.egg,
      this.spawnChance,
      this.avgSpawns,
      this.spawnTime,
      this.multipliers,
      this.weaknesses,
      this.nextEvolution,
      this.prevEvolution});

  Pokemon.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    num = json['num'];
    name = json['name'];
    img = json['img'];
    type = json['type'].cast<String>();
    height = json['height'];
    weight = json['weight'];
    candy = json['candy'];
    candyCount = json['candy_count'];
    egg = json['egg'];
    spawnChance = json['spawn_chance'].toString();
    avgSpawns = json['avg_spawns'].toString();
    spawnTime = json['spawn_time'];
    multipliers = json['multipliers']?.cast<double>();
    weaknesses = json['weaknesses'].cast<String>();
    if (json['next_evolution'] != null) {
      nextEvolution = new List<NextEvolution>();
      json['next_evolution'].forEach((v) {
        nextEvolution.add(new NextEvolution.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['prev_evolution'] != null) {
      prevEvolution = new List<PrevEvolution>();
      json['prev_evolution'].forEach((v) {
        prevEvolution.add(new PrevEvolution.fromJson(v));
    });
  }
}

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['num'] = this.num;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['img'] = this.img;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['height'] = this.height;
    data['weight'] = this.weight;
    data['candy'] = this.candy;
    data['candy_count'] = this.candyCount;
    data['egg'] = this.egg;
    data['spawn_chance'] = this.spawnChance;
    data['avg_spawns'] = this.avgSpawns;
    data['spawn_time'] = this.spawnTime;
    data['multipliers'] = this.multipliers;
    data['weaknesses'] = this.weaknesses;
    if (this.nextEvolution != null) {
      data['next_evolution'] =
          this.nextEvolution.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.prevEvolution != null) {
      data['prev_evolution'] =
          this.prevEvolution.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class NextEvolution {
  String num;
  String name;

  NextEvolution({this.num, this.name});

  NextEvolution.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    num = json['num'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['num'] = this.num;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
}

class PrevEvolution {
  String num;
  String name;

  PrevEvolution({this.num, this.name});

  PrevEvolution.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    num = json['num'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['num'] = this.num;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkMlp.png)

Answer (score 1):

When you wanna paint a Widget, like a Container, all you have to to is set the Color Attribute, which requires, (drumroll.. :P), a Color. Instead of explicitly setting a color in there, you could for example use a function, a switch statement or just  a Map. Basicly anything that makes sure, you get the right color in there..
So instead of

```
Container( 
   color: Colors.red,
   child: ...
```

You could use

```
Container(
   color: _typeColor(pokemon.type.first),
   child: ...
```

Where `_typeColor(pokemon.type.first)` is just a Function, returning a Color.
For example:

```
Color _typeColor(String type) {
   switch(type) { 
      case 'fire':
         return Colors.red; 
      case 'bug':
         return Colors.green; 
      ....
   } 
}
```

Or, if all your Types are Strings you could even use a `Map<String, Color>`

```dart
Map<String, Color> pokemonColors = {'bug': Colors.green, 'fire': Colors.red};
```

and then just set `color: pokemonColors[type]`

Comment: i tried using the function, i put the function inside my class, outside the widget (which i assume to be true). then i put the color : typeColor inside my Card but it gives an error "Instance member 'type' can't be accessed using static access."

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good moment to learn about Dart [extensions](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension PokemonTypeExtension on String {
  Color toPokemonTypeColor() {
    switch (this) {
      case 'fire':
        return Colors.red;
      case 'plant':
        return Colors.blue;
    }
    throw Exception('Type $this is not supported');
  }
}
```

You can use this extension this way :

```dart
Container(
    color: poke.types.first.toPokemonTypeColor(),
    ...
)
```